# updating mongodb with a value which is map which contains a key with '$' in JAVA

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to update mongoDB with a map as a value. This map contains a key which has '$' character in it.

I get following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fields stored in the db can't start with '$' (Bad Key: '$format')
```

My code is:

```
        DB db = new MongoPersistenceManagerImpl().getDB();
        DBObject q = new BasicDBObject();

        DBObject u = new BasicDBObject();
        u.put("details", details);

        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME);
        WriteResult result = collection.update(q, u, true, false);
```

where details is

```
private Map<String, Object> details;
```

One of the key in the "details" map has '$' in it which does not allow me to update mongoDB with the error mentioned above.

The key looks like:

```
http://example.com?$format
```

Please provide pointers to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is an operator prefix in mongodb, you have operators like `$set`, `$in`, `$ne`, etc...
this is the reason you cant use variables that starts with `$` in mongo db. think about it, how can it know if you want to use operator named `$myValue` or just the value `$myVakue` ? it cant, the same reason why you cant name a variable in java `myVar()` or `77Var`.

if you plan to save http address, i would html-encode it

edit:
btw, your problematic value is not http address as you said, but its `$format`, and as the error says, your value **starts** with `$`, you can always store strings that not starts with `$`